# How to make jQuery update the internal elements counter on remove()?

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

I have a list of elements and want to add and remove elements. The list should always contain minimum `x` and maximum `y` elements. An element contains of a text input field and a button to remove the element <kbd>–</kbd>. Add succeeds on cklick on the add button <kbd>+</kbd>.

The problem is, that jQuery [`remove()`](https://api.jquery.com/remove/) seems not to decrease the internal elements counter or maybe doesn't really removes, but only hides the element.

Sure, I could use a variable for counting, but it should also work without it.

**How to make jQuery really remove the element and decrease the internal elements count on remove()?**

---

Background info:

I have a form with an input fields collection `parameter_set`. It should contain minimum `1` test input field and maximum `5` fields.

[image: field and buttons]

```
const PARAMETERS_MIN_NUMBER = 1;
const PARAMETERS_MAX_NUMBER = 5;
$(document).ready(function() {
    addParameterButton = $('#add-parameter-button');
    addParameterButton.on('click', addParameter);
    removeParameterButton = $('.remove-parameter-button');
    removeParameterButton.on('click', removeParameter);
});
function addParameter() {
    var currentCount = $('#my-form .parameters fieldset:first > fieldset').length;
    console.log('add start | current:' + currentCount);
    var template = $('#my-form .parameters fieldset:first > span').data('template');
    template = template.replace(/__index__/g, currentCount);
    if (currentCount < PARAMETERS_MAX_NUMBER) {
        $('#my-form .parameters fieldset:first').append(template);
        removeParameterButton = $('.remove-parameter-button');
        removeParameterButton.on('click', removeParameter);
    }
    currentCount = $('#my-form .parameters fieldset:first > fieldset').length;
    console.log('add stop | current:' + currentCount);
    return false;
}
function removeParameter() {
    var currentCount = $('#my-form .parameters fieldset:first > fieldset').length;
    console.log('remove start | current:' + currentCount);
    if (currentCount > PARAMETERS_MIN_NUMBER) {
        $(this).prev().remove();
        $(this).remove();
    }
    currentCount = $('#my-form .parameters fieldset:first > fieldset').length;
    console.log('remove stop | current:' + currentCount);
    return false;
}

<label class="parameters">
    <span>parameter set</span>
    <fieldset>
        <fieldset>
            <label>
                <span>parameter</span>
                <input type="text" value="" class="form-control field-expression" name="my_form[parameter_set][parameters][0][expression]">
            </label>
            <button value="remove an include parameter" class="btn btn-default button-remove remove-parameter-button" name="parameter_set[parameters][0][remove-parameter]" type="button">&ndash;</button>
        </fieldset>
        <span data-template="the complete fieldset like above with a text-input-field & a remove-button ..."></span>
    </fieldset>
</label>
```

In principle it works, but `remove()` doesn't lead to a reducing of the internal elements counter and brakes the whole logic:

```
initial fields number = $('#my-form .parameters fieldset:first > fieldset').length = 1
click on <kbd>+</kbd>
=> fields number = $('#my-form .parameters fieldset:first > fieldset').length = 2
click on <kbd>-</kbd>
=> fields number = $('#my-form .parameters fieldset:first > fieldset').length = 2 -- and not 1!
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're counting fieldsets, and it looks like you're only removing the button and the label

To recap, you have HTML templates looking like

```
<fieldset>
    <label>
       <span>...</span>
       <input ...>
    </label>
    <button value="remove">&ndash;</button>
</fieldset>
```

When you click the button you do

```
$(this).prev().remove();
$(this).remove();
```

That removes the button and the label, not the fieldset, so the next time you check the length with

```
var currentCount = $('#my-form .parameters fieldset:first > fieldset').length;
```

You still have the same amount of fieldsets.
The solution is probably to just remove the fieldset all together

```
function removeParameter(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    var currentCount = $('#my-form .parameters fieldset:first > fieldset').length;

    if (currentCount > PARAMETERS_MIN_NUMBER) {
        $(this).closest('fieldset').remove();
    }

    currentCount = $('#my-form .parameters fieldset:first > fieldset').length;

    console.log('remove stop | current:' + currentCount);
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your hint! You're right -- The elements are placed in a container element, so I remove the inner elements, but count the containers. :) Replacing `$(this).prev().remove(); $(this).remove();` by `$(this).parent().remove();` resolved my problem.